# Resizable UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am building a custom `UIView` that you can rotate and resize. I can resize the `UIView` by dragging the corners of the `UIView`. I calculate how much I have dragged then change the frame of the `UIView` accordingly.

However, I am running into problems once I added a rotation gesture recognizer to the view. If I rotate or apply a transform to the view, I no longer know how to calculate drag distance and change the frame of the view. How could I calculate the width and height change between my new view and the original view when things are put at an added angle or if they have some other transform, like a translation transform?

I thought of possibilities to set the view's transform back to `.identity`, change the size of the view, then re-apply its transform, but I'm not sure how to actually go about implementing this.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the frame at all. If there are transforms, frame is meaningless.

Comment: You should handle the gestures in the superview. This would allow you to apply the appropriate transformations to the view as deltas and make the calculations much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying transform you  can not use `frame`

You have two options

1) First Calculate everything using `center` of your view

2) As you know apply `identity` and change frame

for point 2 I have added example that might helpful to you

```
    let transform = imageView.transform
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    var rect: CGRect = imageView.frame

    rect = // Change Rect here       

    imageView.frame = rect // Assign it 
    imageView.transform = transform // Apply Transform
```